# Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider> im using redux-ToolKid

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to do crud operation using redux-Toolkit  in react native but it's throwing error.This is my code  can any one explain y

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {View} from "react-native";
import {  configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";  
import userReducer from './src/userData/UserData'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App)

const DataStore=()=>{

    const store = configureStore({
        reducer:{
         user: userReducer
        }
    })
  return (

    <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
    </Provider>


  );
};

export default DataStore
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake in configuring your project structure.

You don't have to edit index.js. Here is my solution:

index.js (original content)

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

And you can edit App.js as below:

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";  
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import userReducer from './src/userData/UserData'

const App = () => {

  const store = configureStore({
      reducer:{
        user: userReducer
      }
  })

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        ...
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>    
  );
};

export default App
```